# R 3D Ellipsoid Graph- How to change axis limits?

Tags: r, rgl

I am trying to make a 3D plot showing the relationship between x, y, and z, based on a sample program I found. However, as you can see in the picture, all the x and y points are clumped together. I need the x and y limits to be from about .35 to.5 and from .275 to .4, respectively. I think the problem may be from this step:

```
Cov <- matrix(c(3,3.5,0,3.5,10,0,0,0,1), 3,3)
```

I am not exactly sure what this line does.

Any help fixing this issue would be much appreciated.

```
data <- read.table(textConnection(
  'x     y     z
  0.461 0.348   5.42
  0.429 0.343   4.99
  0.457 0.336   5.22
  0.402 0.332   4.5
  0.438 0.331   4.66
  0.426 0.33    4.69
  0.43  0.329   4.83
  0.398 0.329   4.41
  0.43  0.326   4.74
  0.426 0.326   4.71
  0.442 0.325   4.81
  0.433 0.322   4.72
  0.407 0.322   4.14
  0.405 0.322   4.43
  0.394 0.322   4.07
  0.384 0.321   4.03
  0.432 0.32    4.64
  0.417 0.319   4.47
  0.409 0.319   4.48
  0.443 0.317   4.59
  0.41  0.317   4.23
  0.417 0.316   4.14
  0.421 0.316   4.46
  0.408 0.316   4.42
  0.405 0.315   4.2
  0.4   0.312   4.17
  0.426 0.307   4.15
  0.395 0.304   4.03
  0.384 0.301   3.77
  0.39  0.299   4.23
  0.414 0.324   4.44
  0.359 0.314   3.54
  0.421 0.307   4.4
  0.415 0.325   4.62
  0.398 0.321   4.25
  0.38  0.306   3.84
  0.394 0.312   3.95
  0.401 0.325   4.16
  0.432 0.315   4.55
  0.42  0.328   4.28
  0.437 0.315   4.5
  0.412 0.322   4.47
  0.396 0.307   4.08
  0.413 0.326   4.12
  0.384 0.31    3.78
  0.393 0.307   4.04
  0.399 0.305   4.3
  0.4   0.312   4.22
  0.421 0.323   4.72
  0.395 0.312   4.28
  0.382 0.303   3.86
  0.396 0.323   4.3
  0.385 0.3     4.01
  0.411 0.311   4.05
  0.406 0.326   4.3
  0.394 0.321   3.99
  0.406 0.314   3.98
  0.413 0.325   4.64
  0.457 0.34    5.5
  0.403 0.321   4.34
  0.376 0.302   3.8
  0.36  0.305   3.54
  0.422 0.311   4.35
  0.369 0.316   3.91
  0.385 0.3     3.79
  0.398 0.31    4.07
  0.365 0.296   3.67
  0.389 0.317   4.13
  0.445 0.327   4.66
  0.426 0.331   4.67
  0.383 0.309   3.88
  0.376 0.314   4.02
  0.406 0.322   4.77
  0.406 0.333   4.43
  0.378 0.317   3.98
  0.397 0.311   4.01
  0.389 0.324   4.41
  0.364 0.308   3.88
  0.38  0.307   3.91
  0.381 0.32    4.5
  0.363 0.302   3.82
  0.404 0.33    4.21
  0.342 0.292   3.3
  0.376 0.3     3.91
  0.388 0.311   4.1
  0.369 0.32    3.82
  0.367 0.317   3.78
  0.375 0.314   3.93
  0.414 0.323   4.46
  0.393 0.321   4.23
  0.391 0.323   4.23
  0.402 0.321   4.25
  0.431 0.313   4.6
  0.446 0.349   5.27
  0.392 0.3     3.72
  0.378 0.302   3.69
  0.391 0.327   4.31
  0.41  0.327   4.6
  0.418 0.323   4.36
  0.434 0.346   4.91
  0.375 0.299   3.77
  0.379 0.315   4
  0.414 0.329   4.52
  0.396 0.326   4.01
  0.335 0.293   3.17
  0.398 0.311   3.95
  0.38  0.312   3.79
  0.366 0.306   3.82
  0.376 0.307   4.01
  0.419 0.327   4.73
  0.384 0.306   3.77
  0.396 0.313   3.91
  0.378 0.308   3.81
  0.39  0.306   3.85
  0.381 0.32    3.88
  0.401 0.332   4.83
  0.408 0.329   4.29
  0.412 0.323   4.48
  0.411 0.318   4.4
  0.398 0.313   4.05
  0.418 0.328   4.53
  0.389 0.32    4.32
  0.417 0.311   4.4
  0.415 0.315   4.53
  0.378 0.302   3.78
  0.422 0.318   4.62
  0.411 0.315   4.13
  0.381 0.324   4.12
  0.436 0.33    4.68
  0.422 0.335   4.48
  0.371 0.302   3.6
  0.4   0.317   4.17
  0.433 0.332   4.73
  0.374 0.317   3.93
  0.382 0.308   3.76
  0.437 0.325   4.79
  0.39  0.325   4.33
  0.386 0.316   4.01
  0.453 0.337   4.96
  0.404 0.31    4.4
  0.4   0.317   4.22
  0.395 0.304   4.02
  0.38  0.319   4.02
  0.369 0.296   3.82
  0.397 0.327   4.43
  0.421 0.338   4.72
  0.394 0.317   4.3
  0.446 0.334   4.99
  0.407 0.309   4.42
  0.428 0.322   4.51
  0.413 0.322   4.51
  0.387 0.308   3.96
  0.413 0.316   4.37
  0.461 0.349   5.4
  0.401 0.314   4.04
  0.388 0.319   4.04
  0.408 0.326   4.54
  0.396 0.317   4.35
  0.41  0.329   4.54
  0.434 0.34    4.86
  0.388 0.318   3.86
  0.374 0.311   3.8
  0.415 0.329   4.51
  0.402 0.313   4.12
  0.375 0.322   4
  0.425 0.325   4.45
  0.36  0.306   3.82
  0.391 0.335   4.43
  0.444 0.343   5.35
  0.369 0.311   3.98
  0.395 0.323   4.4
  0.368 0.309   3.77
  0.349 0.305   3.66
  0.348 0.292   3.43
  0.368 0.303   3.52
  0.425 0.341   4.7
  0.402 0.322   4.36
  0.46  0.34    5.28
  0.413 0.317   4.59
  0.383 0.309   3.88
  0.416 0.325   4.4
  0.401 0.339   4.56
  0.386 0.316   3.78
  0.451 0.339   5.05
  0.401 0.32    4.23
  0.42  0.332   4.64
  0.436 0.338   4.88
  0.378 0.322   3.99
  0.425 0.336   4.75
  0.415 0.335   4.64
  0.403 0.321   4.44
  0.362 0.303   3.77
  0.399 0.331   4.17
  0.39  0.311   4.2
  0.379 0.322   4.12
  0.424 0.335   4.63
  0.422 0.341   4.82
  0.383 0.314   4.05
  0.436 0.35    5.3
  0.378 0.324   4.09
  0.413 0.332   4.77
  0.373 0.304   3.62
  0.371 0.317   4.1
  0.339 0.298   3.17
  0.408 0.321   4.3
  0.402 0.332   4.54
  0.403 0.333   4.95
  0.419 0.338   4.86
  0.454 0.312   4.66
  0.39  0.318   4.04'), header = TRUE)

Mean <- c(0.402,0.319, 4.279)
Mean

Cov <- matrix(c(3,3.5,0,3.5,10,0,0,0,1), 3,3)
Cov


round(var(data),2)
round(Cov - var(data),2)


options(rgl.printRglwidget = TRUE)
open3d()
plot3d(data, box=TRUE,
       xlab="x", ylab="y", zlab="z")
aspect3d("iso")
dataMean <- colMeans(data)
dataCov <- var(data)
plot3d( ellipse3d(Cov,centre=Mean, level=.9),
        col="cyan", alpha=0.5, add = TRUE)][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Cov <-` line is defining a covariance matrix.  I'm assuming these values are leftover from the script you found?  I notice that the `Mean` vector matches the column means of your dataset (`colMeans(data)`), so I'm hoping that all that needs to happen is to update the `Cov` matrix.

The following appeared to work for me (updated to `dataCov` and took out the `aspect3d("iso")` line) - hope it works on your machine too.  BTW - there was a typo in one of your square brackets.

```
options(rgl.printRglwidget = TRUE)
open3d()
plot3d(data, box=TRUE,
   xlab="x", ylab="y", zlab="z")
# aspect3d("iso")  ## this makes it long and skinny and ugly
dataMean <- colMeans(data)
dataCov <- var(data)
plot3d(ellipse3d(dataCov,centre=Mean, level=.9),
    col="cyan", alpha=0.5, add = TRUE)[[1]][1]
```

Comment: edited.  This is just the last bit of code that produces the plot

Comment: Ah, okay, it works. I want to keep the ellipsoid though. I suppose to make it less skinny, the data shouldn't correlate as much?

Comment: So I take it the confidence ellipsoid went away on your machine?  Strange, it still works on mine.  Maybe try removing the `[[1]][1]` since you're probably not interested in returning a value.  As for the `aspect3d` line, it forces the scale to be the same on the x, y, and z axes.  Your data is WAY more spread out in the z direction than in the x or y ... and you'll know best what to do with that from context.

Comment: Thanks now it has a free scale after removing the [[1][1]], I believe.